# How can I access coursework with an unspecified workType value from Google Classroom courseWork API?

Tags: javascript, google-classroom

I am a student in a Google Classroom course where the `courseWork` items always have `workType` values of `"COURSE_WORK_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED"` or `"assignment"`. I use this javascript code to access a [list of courseWork](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list) for my class:

```
function getCourseWork() {
    return gapi.client.classroom.courses.courseWork.list({
     "courseId": mycourseId,
     "pageSize": 100
     })
     .then(function(response) {
        window.coursework = response.result.courseWork
        console.log('getCourseWork(): coursework length='+window.coursework.length)
     },
    function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
}
```

It returns a list of the courseWork where `workType=="assignment"`. However, most of the course content is located in courseWork where `workType=="COURSE_WORK_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED"`, which does not appear in the results. I looked through the `courseWork` documentation, Google, and SO but couldn't find any explanation or mention of this behavior. I tried increasing the `pageSize` argument to ensure the results were not being limited by it.

The only possible lead I have found is in the API documentation for [CourseWorkType](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/CourseWorkType), which contains this note:

> COURSE_WORK_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED: No work type specified. This is never returned.

Am I correct in taking this vague note that only appears in the CourseWorkType documentation to mean that the courseWork.list method can only be used to access courseWork that is an assignment or question?

How can I use the API to access courseWork with an `COURSE_WORK_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED` value for CourseWorkType?

Comment: It appears that this is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115421140) in Google's issue tracker. If anyone knows of a work around in the meantime, that would be awesome.

Comment: Hi ! Are you able to individually [get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/get) any of these ```COURSE_WORK_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED``` courseworks using their id?

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf, I found the id for a `COURSE_WORK_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED` coursework in the `data-stream-item-id` for the item on the Google Classroom site. When I attempt to `get` this coursework, I receive a 404 Not Found error. This method returns the coursework for items that are `workType=="assignment"` just fine.